# Internet Explorer 8 and Firefox 14 Difference in Layout

Tags: html, css, firefox, internet-explorer-8

Sorry for all the code.  It's a pretty basic page really.  I'm stumped.  IE 8 seems to show this page different from ff 14.  For example in ie8, the text in the header seems to be placed relative to it's containing div.  In ff 14, the text seems to be placed relative to the corner of the "wrap" div.  Here are some imagur pics

ie8
http://i.imgur.com/TkgCc.jpg

ff14
http://i.imgur.com/ykdi9.jpg

To make matters worse, my office mate says he uses ie8 and the page looks like my ff14 example to him.  I just installed ie8 so it should be a clean install.

the ie8 version seems to be correct intuitively.  I mean you'd think the text would position itself relative to it's containing div.

any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>title</title>
<STYLE TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>
body
{
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
}
#wrap
{
    width: 900px;
    margin: 30px auto;
}
#left-block
{
    float: left;
    height: 700px;
    width: 140px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    padding: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
    font-size:14px;
}
#left-block h1
{
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
#left-block p
{
    font-weight:900;
}
#left-block li
{
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}
#header
{
    height: 120px;
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#header h2
{
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 90px;
}
#header h1
{
    font-size: 65px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 220px;
}
#nav
{
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#nav ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 190px;
}
#nav ul li
{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}
#nav li a
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}
#nav li a:hover { background: #666; }
#main
{
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000 ;
}
#table
{
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 190px;
}
#footer
{
    text-align: center;
}
#footer h1
{
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}
</STYLE>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="left-block">
        lb
    </div>
    <div id="right-block">
        <div id="header">
            <h2>hd</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
            nav
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            mn
            <div id="table">
                tb
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            ft
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Never, ever use IE as a reference for how things should work. Always, always use a modern browser (anything but IE). Once you know your markup works, then look to see how things are screwed up in IE, but the multitude of problems in IE are well known, as are the hacks to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

At a guess, your browser is jumping into Compatibility Mode. Hit F12 in IE, it will tell you your mode on the grey bar at the top of the web dev area, on the right hand side.

To stop this from happening, add this to your `<head>` area:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />`

This will force IE to use the latest mode available to it and turn on the Chrome frame if installed on the client machine.

Comment: Interesting, while browsing stack overflow with ie8, i get the option to go into compatibility mode. When I open the page in question, the one that I'm working on, there is no option for compatibility mode. I wonder this is because the page I'm working on is a file on my harddrive and not served from a web server? When I added you meta tag:
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
It worked.
Thanks much!

Comment: In IE8, I can use IE7, IE8 or Compatibility modes whether or not the site's hosted online or not. Not sure it's strictly relevant but was interested after you noticed. The mode will be shown next to 'Browser Mode' and will be either Internet Explorer 7, Internet Explorer 8 or Internet Explorer 8 Compatibility View. The option to change this should always be there, even if it's a local file.